# Grand Central Dispatch Looking for a different approach

Tags: swift, functional-programming, sprite-kit, ios9, grand-central-dispatch

```
func RunAfterDelay(delay: NSTimeInterval, block: dispatch_block_t) {
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)
}
```

This Method is being called in a helper class for my game scene. I was following a TUT, and yes I tried to implement the helper class in a current project, I am new to programming. I also new to the idea of GCD, I have read the docs and know it has so great uses....

In my game Scene it is used here:

```
RunAfterDelay(RandomDouble(min: minDelay, max: maxDelay)) { [unowned self] in
    self.createEnemy()
```

It is also used here in the same scene:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
    //   if(self.backgroundMusic.playing){
```

I have found a solution for the sounds, BG Music and Sound effects by creating a global swift file using enums, cases, and public functions to handle music etc. It looks like this I am sure everyone new to Swift has ran into this: RW tuts

```
public class SKTAudio {
public var backgroundMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
public var soundEffectPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

public class func sharedInstance() -> SKTAudio {
    return SKTAudioInstance
```

I am looking for a different approach if there is a better option, as it is currently draining my CPU, after a few runs, and becomes really slow. Thats a different question though. I am more concerned with looking for a better approach than the one listed.

It was a game leveraging SpriteKit and UIKit (for UI reasons) I moved away from that and I am now strictly using SpriteKit.

Comment: If you use GCD, you need to handle concurrency properly, as in all multithreaded programs. GCD is most useful for long-running *independent* computation. It's not a good solution for games.

Comment: Thank you. Very straight forward.

Comment: Would it help if I put up some more code for the Game Scene? In the meanwhile I will look at the information you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a timer in your game scene to spawn things? Or even better, you can use the `update` function to do time based game logic like this. There's a great explanation on this answer: [SpriteKit's Update Function: time vs. framerate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296705/spritekits-update-function-time-vs-famerate)

Those code snippets don't really say much about why you have CPU issues. Are you running on a simulator? You could also try running your block on another thread.

```
func runAfterDelay(selector: Selector, object: AnyObject?, delay: NSTimeInterval) {
    let delay = delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector(selector, toTarget:self, withObject: object)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, after doing some research you have given a different approach to execute this method.

Comment: I am not running on a simulator , as this post is old now, I want to warn people about mixing UIKIT elements and SpriteKit elements. My issue was I was using UIKit for transitions, using manual-segue-ways and the story board to transition scenes. After taking a step back, I realized that although you do use a view controller, (GVC) and it can have UIKit elements (iAds, Game Center, import Social) its better to build the scenes in SpriteKit, as for  GCD and games I am testing with both approaches....